# Dramatically increased CPU time usage when there is an interval between model inferences

Tags: python, pytorch, cpu-usage, onnx

I built a model to classifiy images using PyTorch. And converted it to a ONNX model.
When doing inferences, I noticed that the cpu usage is oddly high when there are intervals between inferences. Regardless of using torch or onnx to inference.

```
%%time
%%timeit -n 50
_ = [sd.infer_scenes([test_img]) for _ in range(5)]
```

7.96 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
CPU times: total: 2.09 s
Wall time: 2.79 s

```
%%time
%%timeit -n 50
time.sleep(0.1)
_ = [sd.infer_scenes([test_img]) for _ in range(5)]
```

113 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
CPU times: total: 7min 24s
Wall time: 39.5 s

```
%%time
%%timeit -n 50
time.sleep(0.00001)
_ = [sd.infer_scenes([test_img]) for _ in range(5)]
```

15.6 ms ± 277 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
CPU times: total: 3.39 s
Wall time: 5.45 s

```
%%time
%%timeit -n 50
time.sleep(0)
_ = [sd.infer_scenes([test_img]) for _ in range(5)]
```

8.02 ms ± 391 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
CPU times: total: 2.05 s
Wall time: 2.81 s

[CPU Usages Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6h8V.png) 
ScenceDetector.py

```
import cv2
import time
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.transforms import transforms

# Define a convolution neural network
class SceneNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SceneNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.channels = 1
        self.shape = self.channels*228*228
        kernel_size = 1
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=self.channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.channels)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.channels, out_channels=self.channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.channels)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.shape, 6)

    def forward(self, input):
        output = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(input)))      
        output = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(output)))     
        output = output.view(-1, self.shape)
        output = self.fc1(output)

        return output

import numpy as np
import onnxruntime as rt

def crop_bottom_right(image): # bottom_right
    height, width = image.shape[0:2]
    w_pct = 0.3
    h_pct = w_pct*width/height
    left = int(width*(1-w_pct))
    up = int(height*(1-h_pct))
    return image[up: height, left: width]

class SceneDetector:

    classes =  ['others', 'inventory', 'minimap_l1', 'minimap_l2', 'map_l1', 'map_l2plus']

    transformations = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Lambda(lambda img: crop_bottom_right(img)),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda img: cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda img: cv2.Canny(image=img, threshold1=50, threshold2=100)),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda img: cv2.resize(img, (448, 448))),
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(), 
        transforms.Normalize((0.5), (0.5))
    ])
    
    def __init__(self, model_path, model = None, is_onnx = False):
        self.is_onnx = is_onnx
        if is_onnx:
            if not model:
                #self.model = rt.InferenceSession(
                #    model_path, providers=rt.get_available_providers())
                self.model = rt.InferenceSession(
                    model_path, providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider'])
            else:
                self.model = model
            self.input_name = self.model.get_inputs()[0].name
        else:
            self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            if not model:
                self.model = SceneNetwork()
                self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
            else:
                self.model = model
            self.model.to(self.device)
            self.model.eval()
            
    def infer_scenes(self, images):
        start = time.time()
        if self.is_onnx:
            images = [ self.transformations(x).numpy() for x in images ]
            outputs = self.model.run(None, {self.input_name: images})[0]
            #predicted = np.argmax(outputs, axis=1)
            _, predicted = torch.max(torch.tensor(outputs), 1)
        else:
            images = torch.stack([ self.transformations(x) for x in images ])
            images = Variable(images.to(self.device))
            start = time.time()
            outputs = self.model(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        print(f'Infer time: {time.time()-start}')
        predicted_class = [ self.classes[x] for x in predicted ]
        return predicted_class
```

At first, I thought it was the problem with the `time.sleep` function.
Then I tried differnet method for delay

1. `threading.Event.wait`
2. `asyncio`'s `await`

The results is the same as `time.sleep`.
Then I tried running the model in a sub process and use `Pipe` to do inference.

```
from SceneDetector import SceneDetector
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process
from threading import Event
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2

def SceneWorker(pipe_conn, model_path, is_onnx = False):
    sd = SceneDetector(model_path, is_onnx = is_onnx)
    while True:
        data = pipe_conn.recv()
        if data is None:
            break

        results = sd.infer_scenes(data)

        pipe_conn.send(results)
        #time.sleep(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_path = 'models/scene_model.onnx'
    scene_conn, scene_child_conn = Pipe()
    scene_process = Process(target=SceneWorker, args=(scene_child_conn, model_path, True,))
    scene_process.start()
    #delay_event = Event()

    test_img = cv2.imread('TestImages/1440P_1000M_8X.jpg') 

    for _ in range(50):
        scene_conn.send([test_img for _ in range(5)])
        results = scene_conn.recv()[0]
        print(results)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        #delay_event.wait(0.0)

    scene_conn.send(None)
    scene_process.join()
```

[Pipelined inference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNbm4.jpg)

And onnx's async inference is also tried.

```
    def infer_callback(self, results, user_data, err) -> None:
        self.results = results
        self.infer_completed.set()
    
    def async_infer_scenes(self, images):
        start = time.time()
        images = [ self.transformations(x).numpy() for x in images ]
        self.model.run_async(None, {self.input_name: images}, self.infer_callback, None)
        self.infer_completed.wait()
        self.infer_completed.clear()
        outputs = self.results[0]
        #predicted = np.argmax(outputs, axis=1)
        _, predicted = torch.max(torch.tensor(outputs), 1)
        print(f'Infer time: {time.time()-start}')
        predicted_class = [ self.classes[x] for x in predicted ]
        return predicted_class
```